# How to migrate Legacy Realm JSON data to MongoDB Realm (Atlas) - problem with relationships

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I'm trying to migrate from Legacy Realm to MongoDB Realm and I'm having trouble migrating data with relationships.

Example schema:

```
{
  name: 'Location',
  primaryKey: '_id',
  properties: {
    _id: 'string',
    _partition: 'string?',
    Name: 'string',
    WorkTime: 'WorkTime[]',
  },
}

{
  name: 'WorkTime',
  primaryKey: '_id',
  properties: {
    _id: 'string',
    _partition: 'string?',
    Day: 'string?',
    Open: 'string?',
    Closed: 'string?',
  },
}
```

In what format should I push the json to MongoDB Atlas, so it links with the related data?

I tried adding the Ids (with and without partition string) from my `WorkTime` collection, following https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Example JSON:

```
{  
   "_id":"adaaade7-2b4f-5342-92a1-f00857a61253"
   "_partition":"TestPartition",  
   "Name":"Test",    
   "WorkTime":[
      {
         "_partition":"TestPartition",
         "_id":"1229ac83-f390-00e3-14a7-ffa9f8eb36e4"
      },
      {
         "_partition":"TestPartition",
         "_id":"9af60ff2-064b-3f09-6621-e7f949b003be"
      },
      {
         "_partition":"TestPartition",
         "_id":"04c33a8c-5e59-45ab-fbf8-e70446324475"
      },   
   ],     
}
```

And when I try to fetch the data from realm (`realm.objects('Location')`), I don't get anything. Locations show up only when `WorkTime` is empty.

I also tried passing the whole `WorkTime` object, instead of Id, but then it creates a copy of the full object.

Comment: You don't have to do much to migrate a Realm file to be used with MongoDB Realm. The objects need to have an _id, which you've done and then you can include a partitionKey property in the actual object. It must also be defined in the Realm console. What does raw JSON have to do with a migration process?

Comment: I need to migrate the data from Legacy Realm to MongoDB Atlas https://docs.realm.io/realm-legacy-migration-guide/#migrating-data

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, the referenced objects need to be Id strings, like in the example. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

So, if you have

```
{  
   "_id":"adaaade7-2b4f-5342-92a1-f00857a61253"
   "_partition":"TestPartition",  
   "Test": {"_id":"9af60ff2-064b-3f09-6621-e7f949b003be", "_partition":"TestPartition"},
   "WorkTime":[
      {
         "_partition":"TestPartition",
         "_id":"1229ac83-f390-00e3-14a7-ffa9f8eb36e4"
      },
   ],     
}
```

should be converted to

```
{  
   "_id":"adaaade7-2b4f-5342-92a1-f00857a61253"
   "_partition":"TestPartition",  
   "Test": "9af60ff2-064b-3f09-6621-e7f949b003be",
   "WorkTime":[
     "1229ac83-f390-00e3-14a7-ffa9f8eb36e4"
   ],     
}
```

Leaving only the Ids as strings.

I iterated though the objects recursively, deleted non-id props of nested objects, replaced Id with _id and added partition key. After that you have to replace the nested objects with string `{"_id":"9af60ff2-064b-3f09-6621-e7f949b003be"} -> 9af60ff2-064b-3f09-6621-e7f949b003be`.

Comment: You really don't need to go through those gyrations unless you are using query based sync, which was not indicated in the question. This mostly only applies to legacy query based sync situations "If your app is designed with legacy query-based sync" from the [guide](https://docs.realm.io/realm-legacy-migration-guide/#legacy-query-based-sync). If your files are local (or full sync), you can update to the new SDK, add the _id and partition Keys, update your code to connect (if sync'ing) and you're done.

Comment: Yes,I'm using full sync. What would the exact steps be to port over the data?
1) open the legacy sync realm, so it downloads the files
2) replace id with _id and add _partition in the model
3) update to realm 10
4) open a mongodb sync realm with a matching partitionValue (if it was `realmUrl/test` in legacy, should it be `/test` or just `test` in mongo)?
5) data would be ported over automatically?

Comment: I don't know what your prior versions were but you may just be able to open the realm File with Realm Studio to upgrade it. I would make a copy of your local file and try that. Otherwise keep in mind moving to MongoDB Realm has a different local file structure. So for example you could have had a local file called `default.realm` that was full sync'd to the legacy realm cloud. When you use MongoDB Realm, the structure will be quite different as each 'realm' file is stored by partition.

Comment: I've been using v6.1.5. My synced files in `realm-object-server\guid` are without extension, with .lock or empty folders. This is really confusing, I thought realm studio can work only with legacy files. A step by step guide would be really helpful (something similar to what I wrote in my previous comment).

Comment: The legacy Realm Object Server/Browser would only work with legacy Realm files. Then it became Realm Studio which would only work with legacy files. Once [Realm Studio](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases) (scroll down to read the release noves) was updated to v4.0.0, it would work with the new files (file format v10) and also upgrade older files.

Comment: Can it handle duplicate ids in realms (ex. enum data, like message status)? Since with mongo db, everything is in a single db, separated with partitions, I'm not sure that would be feasible. Unless its possible to to have a relationship pointing to an id of a different partition (and on top of that avoid duplicating these statuses for each partition)